# java- how to check type of response sent (response is in JSON Format)

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to connect to an API that returns data in JSON format.
After initially logging in to that site, I am assigned a Session ID- in all further API calls I have to provide that session ID as an input parameter.

Now, for example, I am trying to make a call to the API.

If the session ID i have provided is correct, then the response will be in a format that I have information about.

However if the session ID I give is incorrect, then the JSON response will be similar to the following--

```
     {"code": "ERROR", "detail": "Session ID is invalid"}
```

I am using Google GSON to map the json response to a java class... How do I know whether the response is with the data (ie when my session ID is correct and the API is returning the data I am expecting), or whether the response is of the above format.

The only thing I could think of is to search for existence of (for example) "Session ID is invalid" within the response string. Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could also check for `"code"\s*:\s*"ERROR"`, but maybe you also get a http status code that you can check (maybe you get a 401 or so).